# Procedure to insert record in table from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to insert record in another table,from another table with extra param as well.Following are tables

[image]

I want to insert project_access as userName as param and Project access as hard code value as "Y" and rest all values from project table. I am new to sql.
Can somebody help me

In project access
User_ID- should be param of procedure
Project_object_id as Project id or project table
Project_access_id is generated by sequence
Project_access as Y in all rows
Project Name should be project name of project.

Comment: Sample data and desire results would clarify what you want to do.  Your question also mentions things like "userName", "param", and "hard code value" that are not identified in the data model you provide.

Comment: i want to insert records in project_access table from project records

Comment: User_ID- should be param of procedure Project_object_id as Project id or project table Project_access_id is generated by sequence Project_access as Y in all rows Project Name should be project name of projec

Comment: Just repeating what you already said in the question doesn't help to make us understand. We can read, we don't understand what you want.

Comment: Sorry for not explaning clearly. Project access table should be filled with all rows of project table having two column from project table. Rest two column will be hard code.   So for example, I want in project for userid- "abc" all project id and project name should be added in project acccess table with project id and project name from project table. Project Access as Y in all row and user id with abc in all. Hope it clear now

Answer (score 1):

You may need something like the following:

```
insert into tableTarget( column1, column2, column3)
select column1, column2, 'hardcoded value'
from tableSource
```

In a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure yourProc(x in number) as
begin
    insert into tableTarget( column1, column2, column3)
    select column1, column2, x
    from tableSource;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks.  how to get it in stored procedure. And how if hardcoded value coming as in param

Comment: I tried same thing like below                                                                                         create or replace PROCEDURE populateResource
( username IN varchar2 )
IS
BEGIN

 insert into PROJECT_ACCESS
(User_ID, PROJECT_OBJECT_ID,PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_ACCESS_ID, PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_ACCESS,PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_NAME)
select username,PROJECT.PROJECT_ID,PROJECT_ACCESS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'Y', PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME
from PROJECT

  COMMIT;

END;                                          But it giving me comple time error

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE populateResource
( username IN varchar2 )
IS
BEGIN

 insert into PROJECT_ACCESS
(User_ID, PROJECT_OBJECT_ID,PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_ACCESS_ID, PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_ACCESS,PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_NAME)
select username,PROJECT.PROJECT_ID,PROJECT_ACCESS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'Y', PROJECT.PROJECT_NAME
from PROJECT

  COMMIT;

END;

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after  `from PROJECT`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE grantUserProjectAccess(
  in_user_id           IN  PROJECT_ACCESS.USER_ID%TYPE,
  in_project_object_id IN  PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_OBJECT_ID%TYPE,
  out_error            OUT VARCHAR2
)
AS
  v_project_name PROJECT_ACCESS.PROJECT_NAME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT project_name
  INTO   v_project_name
  FROM   project
  WHERE  project_object_id = in_project_object_id;

  INSERT INTO project_access (
    user_id,
    project_object_id,
    project_access_id,
    project_access,
    project_name
  ) VALUES (
    in_user_id,
    in_project_object_id,
    PROJECT_ACCESS_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    'Y',
    v_project_name
  );

  out_error := NULL;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    out_error   := 'Project Not Found';
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    out_error   := 'Duplicate Entry';
END;
/
```

*(Note: Do not call commit inside procedures unless you have a very good reason - commit the data in the outermost block calling the procedure - this will allow you to nest calls to procedures and, if necessary, issue a `ROLLBACK` on the entire sequence of procedures. If you only want to do a partial rollback then consider using `SAVEPOINT`s.)*